# How can i solve this error in my Laravel Framework? In Vendor Directory has Error

Tags: php, mysql, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I need assistance with an error that has occurred after installing Laravel. The issue seems to be with the vendor directory, as it is showing an error. Can someone provide guidance or help me resolve this problem?

I attempted to troubleshoot the issue by checking my Laravel and Composer versions. I made sure that I have the latest versions installed, including Composer version 2.5.8 and Laravel Installer version 4.5.0. Despite this, I am still encountering the error in the vendor directory. I was expecting the update to resolve the problem, but it seems there might be something else causing the issue.

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/laravel/framework/tests/Foundation/fixtures/bad-syntax-strategy.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token ')'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 2
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/laravel/pint/tests/Fixtures/with-non-fixable-issues/file.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token ''",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 18,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 18
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/mockery/mockery/tests/Fixture/PHP83/Enums.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token 'FOO'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 18,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 21
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/mockery/mockery/tests/Fixture/PHP83/Interfaces.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token 'BAR'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 18,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 21
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/mockery/mockery/tests/Fixture/PHP83/Traits.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token 'BAR'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 18,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 21
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/mockery/mockery/tests/Unit/PHP83/Php83LanguageFeaturesTest.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token ')'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 51,
    "startColumn": 65,
    "endLineNumber": 51,
    "endColumn": 66
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/tests/_files/source_for_branched_exec_lines.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token '&'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 61,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 61,
    "endColumn": 10
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/spatie/ignition/tests/TestClasses/ClassWithSyntaxError.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token 'error'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 9,
    "startColumn": 16,
    "endLineNumber": 9,
    "endColumn": 21
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/spatie/laravel-ignition/tests/stubs/Controllers/GitConflictController.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token '<<'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 12,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 12,
    "endColumn": 11
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/ramsey/uuid/tests/Type/DecimalTest.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP0009",
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "The integer number 9223372036854775809 is too big, converting to double instead",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 159,
    "startColumn": 29,
    "endLineNumber": 159,
    "endColumn": 48
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/ramsey/uuid/tests/Type/DecimalTest.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP0009",
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "The integer number 9223372036854775808 is too big, converting to double instead",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 164,
    "startColumn": 28,
    "endLineNumber": 164,
    "endColumn": 47
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/ramsey/uuid/tests/Type/IntegerTest.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP0009",
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "The integer number 9223372036854775809 is too big, converting to double instead",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 183,
    "startColumn": 15,
    "endLineNumber": 183,
    "endColumn": 34
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/laravel/pizzahouse/vendor/ramsey/uuid/tests/Type/IntegerTest.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "PHP0009",
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "The integer number 9223372036854775808 is too big, converting to double instead",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 190,
    "startColumn": 14,
    "endLineNumber": 190,
    "endColumn": 33
}]
```

Comment: wrong php version most likely, if you have syntax errors in laravel framework, check the php version of your webserver like apache, and not the cli one, because even if you have the correct version when doing php -v, it does not means your webserver use the same version. For laravel 10 you need php 8.1 minimum

Comment: Ensure you have installed proper PHP version for specified Laravel version

Comment: Also, the last laravel installer is 5.0.3, if you are stuck on 4.5.1, it means you have php ^7.3 or php ^8.0, did you use the --ignore-platform-reqs flag ? it should not let you install an incompatible version, perhaps the vendor directory was copied to your computed somehow ?

Comment: Can you share the code involved? How do you call the code? Which error are you facing? How is this related to MySQL or Composer?

Comment: Right now I have Laravel Installer 4.5.0 and PHP 8.2.0 so I need to update my Laravel installer to the latest? to make it compatible?